# VLANs setup via untagged hybrid ports on ProCurve switch?

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

**Is this a path to set up VLANs in my small office with a hp V1910 series ProCurve switch?**
... and what am I missing?

The network is /24, so all IPs are in the same 192.168.0.X subnet. The switch is a V1910-24G and is currently operational with the factory default configuration which is all ports untagged on VLAN001 and VLan1-interface is set on 192.168.0.5. The *firewall / gateway / router / dhcp server* is on 192.168.0.2 running pfsense. To get everyone access to the internet, I set up a static route from `0.0.0.0` of netmask `0.0.0.0` to the pfsense firewall on `192.168.0.2`. The DHCP server has set every client's gateway to the switch on `192.168.0.5`.

The goal is isolating network functional tasks from each other while still including common services: access to the RAID, the Internet, and the printers:

[image: VLANs setup via untagged hybrid ports]

So far, everything I try to accomplish to improve the network has resulted in failure of some sort or another, especially attempts at setting up Vlan-Interfaces and static routing. However, [a comment in a different QA](https://serverfault.com/questions/567268/configuring-vlans-on-hp-1910-switch):

> *"Hybrid ports can have multiple untagged VLANs.  Which makes absolutely no sense to 
>   me...why would you do that? Hoping someone can clear that part up."* <sub>Grant -- Jan 15 at  21:10</sub>

... unlocked the concept for me of what I was visualizing from the beginning: a simple way to contain workplace functions grouped by physical ports. I'll start attempting to implement this tomorrow after shipping has concluded (and we're done making $ from the internet).

From the research I've done, mapping VLANs by port [isn't preferred](https://superuser.com/questions/530335/how-to-setup-vlan-on-same-subnet-as-ethernet); however, there are only 5 of us here and I'm the only person mucking about with voodoo. Everyone else sits at their computer and just wants to get work done.

"Tagged" options available once this is working:
1) I'd like to get "voice" VLAN working with the VoIP SIP boxes, but I suspect that will be another question. I tried today and that failed spectacularly. I did enjoy the quiet of no phones ringing...
2) Enable QoS for the VoIP boxes.
3) The RAID server is a Debian 7.3 host and I could set up tagging and VLANs on this box and then change its port to a "trunk" if that would get a theoretical performance improvement.

Everything but the VoIP and printers is Gigabit and the [network is like in this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/564410/improvements-for-small-business-network), only the Dell has been replaced by the hp ProCurve.

The best links from my research so far:
https://serverfault.com/questions/392453/understanding-vlan
http://vmfocus.com/2012/09/26/how-to-configure-layer-3-static-routes-vlans-on-hp-v1910-24g
https://serverfault.com/questions/567268/configuring-vlans-on-hp-1910-switch